# HP ProCurve Stacking

Tags: hp-procurve, stacking

How do i telnet back?

I have done stacking using 2 dummy HP Pro Curve 2610.
Gateway for Commander is 192.168.1.1 , while member has 192.168.1.2.

I was in Commander Switch, then i telnet to the Member Switch.

The issue was that, when i am in Member Switch, i could not telnet back to Commander Switch.

I realize that when i use "Sh Stack All" , my Commander Switch does not have Commander IP.

How do i rectify all these and telnet back to Commander?

Commander is 1-0
Member is 1-1

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you nest telnet sessions, you just need to exit the last one to get back to the previous one. In your case, the chain would be Putty->Commander->Member. By exiting the Member session, you'll get back to the commander.